# Looping from the second list item onwards

Tags: ansible

How can I loop from the second item of a list onward?

Vars

```yaml
file_list
  - { file_name: "application.log", file_location: "/home/application" }
  - { file_name: "eai_new.log", file_location: "/home/eai_new" }
  - { file_name: "base.log", file_location: "/home/base" }
```

Here is my task:

```yaml
- command: "filename = {{ item.file_name}}, file location = {{ item.file_location }}"
  loop: "{{ file_list}}"
  when: item.file_location != ""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you need,

You need to use the concept of slicing a list in Python.
Let say you have a list,

```
x = [1,2,3]
```

And you want your list to start from the second element, you can slice out the first element to get a new list

```
y = x[1:]
```

Then list y will hold the following value,

```
y = [2,3]
```

Sample playbook,

```
---
  - name: iterate from the second element
    hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    tasks:
      - name: set a list
        set_fact:
          file_list:
             - { file_name: "application.log", file_location: "/home/application" }
             - { file_name: "eai_new.log", file_location: "/home/eai_new" }
             - { file_name: "base.log", file_location: "/home/base" }

      - name: iterate over the list
        debug:
          msg: "{{ item.file_name }}"
        loop: "{{ file_list[1:] }}"
```

Sample Output

```
TASK [iterate over the list] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'file_name': 'eai_new.log', 'file_location': '/home/eai_new'}) => {
    "msg": "eai_new.log"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'file_name': 'base.log', 'file_location': '/home/base'}) => {
    "msg": "base.log"
}
```

Comment: hi can i know if want to refer first element cant do this [0]? as i tried was not working, i tried this [:1], was working, but would like to know why [0] could not work. u have any idea please share

Comment: `loop` expects a list and if you give `file_list[0]` it's not a list but a dictionary. So, in case you wish to only iterate of a single element, you can use something like `loop: "[ {{ file_list[0] }} ]" `

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of `loop_control` `index_var` directive, eg:

```yaml
- name: Loop over every 2nd element
  hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    foo:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
      - 4
      - 5
      - 6

  tasks:
    - name: Loop
      debug:
        msg: "{{ idx }}"
      loop: "{{ foo }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: idx
      when: idx % 2 == 0
```

Which produces:

```json
TASK [Loop] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
    "msg": 0
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) => {
    "msg": 2
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=4) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=5) => {
    "msg": 4
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=6)
```